# How to hide dropdown toggle button in syncfusion

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am working on Syncfusion Xamarin(c# & XAML) Combobox. I am trying to hide the toggle button on the dropdown but I couldn't achieve it and I couldn't find anything on the documentation.

**Code**

```
                                <time:CustomComboBox
                                x:Name="type"
                                BorderColor="#a4a4a4"
                                DataSource="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                DropDownTextSize="14"
                                HeightRequest="45"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding isEnable}"
                                IsSelectedItemsVisibleInDropDown="False"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding DType.Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                ShowBorder="False"
                                ShowClearButton="False"
                                SuggestionBoxPlacement="Bottom"
                                TextColor="#8793EF"
                                TextSize="15" />
```

I tried **visibility** but it is hiding the entire thing.

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/combobox/customizing-combobox#view-for-drop-down-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have prepared a sample based on your requirement using DropDownButtonSettings Width & Height property. Please get the sample from the attachments and below are the code snippet.

Sample link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DropdownToggleButton-1827799984

```
<time:SfComboBox
                    x:Name="type"
                    BorderColor="#a4a4a4"
                    DataSource="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    DropDownTextSize="14"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnable}"
                    IsSelectedItemsVisibleInDropDown="False"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ShowBorder="False"
                    ShowClearButton="False"
                    SuggestionBoxPlacement="Bottom"
                    TextColor="#8793EF"
                    TextSize="15">
                    <time:SfComboBox.DropDownButtonSettings>
                       <time:DropDownButtonSettings Width="0" Height="0">
                    </time:DropDownButtonSettings>
                  </time:SfComboBox.DropDownButtonSettings>
 </time:SfComboBox>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow the use of zip files as links please  remove the zip file and create a gist of the code.